Can't "Copy Data Path". How do I fix it?
This is my first time using blender and I was trying to setup a driving system for FK/IK Switch for the arms but when I tried to copy data path for the Main bone, I couldnt?
This is what my screen looks like currently:


I've tried turning on python tool tips as well as tried installing python to my computer. I have also tried deleting and creating a new custom property for the bone as well

Nevermind I realized I cant place a custom property like that on my bones. I had to attach it to my armature.
